# function randomly doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

the program is meant to remove the first number from the array and check if what the second is and display the image that is linked. the code randomly stops working on the button press then after couple press it starts working again

```js
var deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function myFunction() {
  deck.sort(function(a, b) {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  });
  deck.shift();

  if (deck[0] == "1") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2478399688/6gyep59fumb340ima588_400x400.png";
  } else if (deck[0] == "2") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.printablee.com/postpic/2014/08/number-2-printable-coloring-pages_244062.jpg";
  } else if (deck[0] == "3") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://blogs.abc.net.au/.a/6a00e0097e4e688833017eeb4172f2970d-800wi";
  } else if (deck[0] == "4") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/309/blog-numbers-just-numbers-page-2-9bq8wQ-clipart.jpg";
  } else if (deck[0] == "5") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/527cff9fe4b0dc36171a857c/52b21af3e4b07a50584fa6f2/553bd231e4b0bfb591495953/1429983793686/5.png?format=750w";
  } else if (deck[0] == "6") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.drodd.com/images15/6-6.jpg";
  } else if (deck[0] == "7") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.drodd.com/images15/number7-5.jpg";
  } else if (deck[0] == "8") {
    document.getElementById("img").src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d2fkzKP2A3M/maxresdefault.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<img src="" id="img" />
```

Comment: What is is supposed to do?

Comment: You know that `shift` removes an element from the array? What should happen if the `deck` array is empty?

Comment: @gus27 its meant to be removed just haven't put in the if statement for if its empty

Comment: You have neither explained what is going wrong nor the expected behavior of this code.  You're asking for help to fix it.  "It does not work" does not cut it.

Comment: Like Tibrogargan said: I see a button and when I press it an image appears. Seems to be working...

Comment: I can't see what the problem..

Comment: Perhaps ... `var deck = [ "url1", "url2", "url3", ... ].sort( () => 0.5 - Math.random()); function myFunction() { document.getElementById("img").src = deck.shift(); }`

Comment: You are doing `array.shift` so after `8` iterations, you array will be blank and `deck[0]` will be `undefined`

Comment: @rajesh it happens before it runs out

Comment: You really have to explain how you determine that it "stops working". Does it show a broken image? Does it show the same image? Are there any messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @gus27 it doesn't switch images. and in console the id doesn't change either

Comment: it doesn't "stop working" - it merely happens to display the same image! you should "shift" AFTER you display the image, that way you wont display the same image again

Comment: @DeadPixle That the id and the image doesn't change between clicks could be considered normal behaviour because of your random sort.

Comment: @Jaromanda X thanks i am stupid

Comment: @DeadPixle - no, you simply made a mistake. What helped (for future reference) is `console.log(deck)` just after the `deck.shift()` statement - then it became obvious what was actually happening when looking at the Developer Tools Console - available in all good browsers :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but maybe you will find some of these things useful.

- You don't need to resort the array, one random sort is enough
- Unless you're going to regenerate the array, you can just use the URLs instead of indexes
- Don't shift() before you use your first image, or it will get lost forever.
- Maybe resize your images to fit
- You're better off adding a click handler with code to preserve separation of form and function
- Avoid using repeated `else if`, the `switch` statement is more effective - or you could use the data structure itself
- `src=''` is illegal in some browsers, `src='//:0'` is apparently a better alternative

```js
blank = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=";
deck = [ "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2478399688/6gyep59fumb340ima588_400x400.png"
       , "http://www.printablee.com/postpic/2014/08/number-2-printable-coloring-pages_244062.jpg"
       , "http://blogs.abc.net.au/.a/6a00e0097e4e688833017eeb4172f2970d-800wi"
       , "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/309/blog-numbers-just-numbers-page-2-9bq8wQ-clipart.jpg"
       , "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/527cff9fe4b0dc36171a857c/52b21af3e4b07a50584fa6f2/553bd231e4b0bfb591495953/1429983793686/5.png?format=750w"
       , "http://www.drodd.com/images15/6-6.jpg"
       , "http://www.drodd.com/images15/number7-5.jpg"
       , "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d2fkzKP2A3M/maxresdefault.jpg"
       ].sort( () => 0.5 - Math.random() );

function myFunction() { document.getElementById("img").src = deck.length? deck.shift() : blank; }

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
    document.getElementById("img").src = blank;
}
, false);
```

```html
<button id="button">Try it</button><br />
<img src="//:0" width="50" height="50" id="img" />
```